# In-App using ProductStore native extension

Tags: air, in-app-purchase, air-native-extension

I am testing my app in-app purchase feature, when I trigger the buy option

`productStore.makePurchaseTransaction(product,quantety);`

nothing happens, and non of the following events trigger:

```
productStore.addEventListener(TransactionEvent.PURCHASE_TRANSACTION_SUCCESS, purchaseTransactionSucceeded);
        productStore.addEventListener(TransactionEvent.PURCHASE_TRANSACTION_CANCEL, purchaseTransactionCanceled);
        productStore.addEventListener(TransactionEvent.PURCHASE_TRANSACTION_FAIL, purchaseTransactionFailed);
```

I don't have a clue to what is the error, when I ask for the product details

```
productStore.requestProductsDetails(vector);
```

It fails:

```
productDetailsFailed[ProductEvent type="productDetailsFail" bubbles=false cancelable=false products=null invalidIdentifiers=myapp.fullVersion,null error=null]
```

Any advice on this issue will be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
invalidIdentifiers=myapp.fullVersion
```

Your application doesn't have this *inapp* purchase ability.

Check itunes for *inapp* connect.